# char pointer file I/O

Tags: c++, file, pointers, char

I am struggling to understand the behaviour of the program. The test.txt file is of 16 bytes where as the size of text pointed by pointer p of structure is more than 16 bytes(the string text) there are other int values too. How the extra data is stored in test file with only 16 bytes. The file is read by another structure 'b' but it gives correct values like 'a'.

```
int main() 
{
    string text("C:\\Users\\Chitra\\Desktop\\Capture.JPG"); 
    string filepath("C:\\Users\\Chitra\\Desktop\\New folder\\Project1\\Project1\\test.txt");

    fstream fout(filepath,ios::out|ios::binary); 
    fstream fin(filepath,ios::in|ios::binary);

    struct block 
    { 
        int value; 
        int size; 
        const char* p; 
        int some;
    };

    block a;  
    a.value = 1457745; 
    a.size = text.length(); 
    a.p = text.c_str();  
    a.some = 97877;
 
    fout.write((char*)&a, sizeof(a));  
    fout.close();  

    block b;
    fin.read((char*)&b, sizeof(b)); 
    fin.seekg(0, ios::end);

    cout << "file size " << fin.tellg();
    fin.close();

    cout << "\nsize a " << sizeof(a) << "  size b " << sizeof(b);
    cout << "\n"<<b.value << "  " << b.size << "  " << b.p << "  " << b.some;
    getchar();  

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: People editing (broken) code suggestions into the question makes it damned near impossible for others to understand existing answer and comments, or match the problem description to the code.  People should post corrected code ***in their answers***, or if user2806369 wants to - ***append*** a "working version" as an EDIT to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The file is only 16 bytes because when you write a.p to the file, you are writing a four-byte pointer value which points to the string in memory -- you are not writing out the string data itself.

The reason that it appears to work is that you immediately read the same pointer value back into another pointer variable in the same process, so when you read the memory pointed to by b.p, it is the same as the memory pointed to by a.p, that is, the NUL-terminated string text.

If you created a second program which just did the file read, without declaring the string text, you should expect to encounter an error or at least, not see the text.

```
int main() 
{
    string filepath("C:\\Users\\Chitra\\Desktop\\New folder\\Project1\\Project1\\test.txt");

    fstream fin(filepath,ios::in|ios::binary);

    struct block 
    { 
        int value; 
        int size; 
        const char* p; 
        int some;
    };

    block b;
    fin.read((char*)&b, sizeof(b)); 
    fin.seekg(0, ios::end);

    cout << "file size " << fin.tellg();
    fin.close();

    cout << "\n  size b " << sizeof(b);
    cout << "\n"<<b.value << "  " << b.size << "  " << b.p << "  " << b.some;
    getchar();  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Work around, provided i am not allowed to change the member variables of struct block.

Comment: I'm not proposing you change `struct block`; I'm suggesting you try compiling and running a program like the one attached above. (in the edit)

Comment: There are a few different ways to write strings to binary files; the two most commonly used are to just write the NUL-terminated string, e.g.

`fout.write(str.c_str(), str.length()+1)`

The other commonly used option is to write a length first, and then write the string data, either terminated or unterminated:

`size_t s = str.length();`
`fout.write(&s, sizeof(s));`
`fout.write(str.c_str(), s);`

Comment: But this way i have to write string individually, not the complete struct

Comment: Ah, I understand your comment now.  You're asking, how do I work around this?

If you're not able to change the layout of block but can add member functions, you could add an `operator <<(ostream&)` that writes either the NUL-terminated data or the length first.

If you're not able to add member functions, you could write an `operator <<(ostream& , struct block)` that does the same thing.

Comment: insertion operator limit is white spaces(which is not in my case but surely it can fail in other case)

Comment: Are you designing a binary file format for some purpose?  Or are you trying to understand how writing to binary files works?

Comment: rying to understand how writing to binary files works

Comment: It's a pretty big topic.  Part of what I do for a living is reverse-engineer undocumented binary file formats.

When writing a character string, the most common approaches are :

1. declare a fixed maximum length and write the string, with zero padding.  If you can change your data structure, you would change the member to char name[40] (or whatever length) instead of char * name

This is probably the simplest way.

Comment: 2. write the length before the data, as a two-step process.

If you do this, you can support arbitrarily long strings, but you have to read and write as a two-step process.  You cannot just write the struct to disk, as discussed above.

Comment: 3. (worst option) write the string data without writing the length beforehand.  Now your reader routine will not now how much memory to allocate for the string, so will have to guess at an initial buffer size and reallocate memory if needed.  This is error-prone.

Comment: There is also not very  intuitive work around. i tried it long before for declaring static array as dynamic yes.What i did is wrote the code to another file as code(code was streamed like cout),filestream<<"int array["<<size<<"];";//int array[size];.Pretty weird is'nt

Answer (score 0):

as Sam Mikes said block.p is pointer and you only save its value (the value of a pointer is an address of the memory it point) and because of a.p is still point to it in memory the memory do not change add `delete a;` like code bellow and see the different

*noted that : sizeof a and b and block is the same you can use `sizeof(a) or sizeof(b) or sizeof(block)` instead

```
#include <string>
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
string text("C:\\Users\\Chitra\\Desktop\\Capture.JPG"); 
string filepath("C:\\Users\\Chitra\\Desktop\\New folder\\Project1\\Project1\\test.txt");
fstream fout(filepath,ios::out|ios::binary); 
fstream fin(filepath,ios::in|ios::binary);

struct block { 
   int value; 
   int size; 
   const char* p;
   int some;
};
block a;
a.value =1457745;
a.size=text.length();
a.p=text.c_str();
a. some=97877;

fout.write((char*)&a,sizeof(a)); 
fout.close();

delete a.p;

block b;
fin.read((char*)&b,sizeof(b)); 
fin.seekg(0,ios::end);
cout<<"file size "<<fin.tellg();
fin.close();
cout<<"\nsize a "<<sizeof(a)<<"  size b "<<sizeof(b)<<"  size block "<<sizeof (block);
cout<<"\n"<<b.value<<"  "<<b.size<<"  "<<b.p<<"  "<<b.some;
getchar();  
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can't just do...

```
fout.write(pointer, bytes);
```

...for *any* values of `pointer` and `byte`, because the data doesn't exist in contiguous memory.  You *must* write the data embedded in the `block` without the pointer, and the pointed-to string data, separately.  That's easiest if you move the pointer to the end of the structure, then write:

```
struct block 
{ 
    int value; 
    int some;
    int size; 
    const char* p; 
};

fout.write((char*)&a, sizeof a - sizeof a.p);
           // could also "offsetof(block, p)" for size - possibly more fragile
fout.write(a.p, a.size);
```

Then, to read the data back:

```
block b;
fin.read((char*)&b, sizeof b - sizeof b.p);
b.p = new char[b.size + 1];
fin.read(b.p, b.size);
b.p[b.size + 1] = '\0';  // guarantee NUL termination
```

Sometime later you'll need to `delete[] b.p;` to deallocate the memory returned by the `new[]`.  Alternatively, you could use another `string`:

```
block b;
fin.read((char*)&b, sizeof b - sizeof b.p);
std::string b_string(b.size, ' ');  // initially b.size spaces
fin.read(&b_string[0], b.size);     // overwrite with data from the file...
```

With the `std::string`, deallocation happens automatically when the destructor is invoked.

(It's actually best to use a C++ serialisation library with `std::fstream`s, like [boost's here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).)